# MPICH2 on a machine with two NUMA nodes

Tags: performance, mpi, cpu-architecture

I am new to MPI. I am using MPICH2 on a Linux machine with the following information:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                40
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               799.844
CPU max MHz:           3000.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4400.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              14080K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-9,20-29
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     10-19,30-39
```

My understanding is that I've got 2 nodes, 20 cores and 40 threads (i.e. processors) on this machine. Is this correct? If yes, I think I should set MPICH to spawn 20 processes (one process on each physical core), right? However, when I run the command `mpiexec -n 20 MyProgram`, the average CPU usage is only 50%. If I change to `mpiexec -n 40 MyProgram`, the CPU usage is 100% but the overall performance is actually becoming worse so I think I might be over-specifying.

Comment: You have 2 sockets with 10 cores each one. Besides, with the hyper-threading, each core can simultaneously handle 2 threads. You are creating 40 processes in the mpiexec command and it seems that your application is not likely to leverage hyper-threading. So, I recommend you disable hyper-threading or spawn only 20 processes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean for other applicaions that support hyper-threading, I can create 40 processes to reach a 100% CPU  consumption given my hardware?    Also, I added the option --gforker when compiling MPICH, would that cause the problem?

Comment: It is really application dependent, so you could find an application that leveraged those 40 processes.

Comment: How do you measure CPU usage? Typically Linux (e.g. top) reports 100% CPU usage for one active core, so you should see 2000% / 4000% respectively.

Comment: I measured CPU usage using the "GPU average" in htop command. I think it is an averaged value of all cores.

Answer (score 0):

CPU usage is a misleading metric. CPU usage reflects the portion of time some task was scheduled on a logical CPU. CPU average is just that, the average over all logical cores. So 50% CPU average can just mean that every other logical CPU has 100% usage, (and the others 0 %). So you observe this in a situation where each physical core is always utilized.

CPU usage, does mean resource utilization. There are workloads that benefit from using hyperthreading and workloads that don't. There are workloads that can be faster using less threads than physical cores (e.g. memory bandwidth limited). There are workloads that can be faster using more threads than logical CPUs (e.g. I/O latency limited).

Always use your performance metric (e.g. time) to figure out the best configuration. If you want to understand resource utilization you must look at many different performance metrics, cycles, instructions, memory bandwidth, cache, ....